# Unable to scroll down

Tags: scroll

I'm struggling on my website which worked well since the [shareaholic widget](https://shareaholic.com/) install. I've tried to remove it but the bug remains.

A picture is worth thousand words so it's about : [www.mywebshop.org](http://www.mywebshop.org), we can't scroll anymore on the website and I must admit I've never seen that bug (except when using fixed position ;-)).

I'm totally stuck... no cache is active, I can't see anything out of the ordinary... I'm having this issue on every browser on my mac.

Any clues?

Thank in advance ;-)

Comment: Just for information, this website is responsive and the bug is still present on tablets but not in smartphones...

Answer (score 1):

hey there I have seen your site. Please remove the overflow-y:hidden; from the body selector in the style.css file on line number:2793

That should do it

Comment: Hi, i've removed it and it's working again (genius !!) ;-) But it's strange.. why did it worked well until now ?

Comment: May be its because of your browser cache,
always a pleasure

Comment: Again, thank you, I can't "vote up" for you but I would have done with pleasure ;)